# Call content from different location in page in Angular Tabs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of tabs.  I want to know how to get content from a different part of the page when the tab is clicked.  I can do it by calling a different html page, but is there a way to display content from the same page?

```
   <tabset vertical="false">
            <tab heading="Scenario 1">Test</tab>
            <tab heading="Scenario 2"></tab>
            <tab heading="Dist as of 12/31/15"></tab>
            <tab heading="Custom Label"></tab>
   </tabset>
```

For example, how would I get the content for Scenario1 to display in the tab for scenario one.  I know I can put everything in-between the tab markup, but is there another way to do it.

.js page

```
(function () {
'use strict'

var DistributionApp = angular.module('DistributionApp',
['someApp', 'ctracApp.engagement.services', 'ngRoute']);

DistributionApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Distribution',
    {
        templateUrl: '/app/Something/Distribution/Distribution.html',
        controller: 'distributionCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'minimumDist'
    });
}]);


DistributionApp.controller('distributionCtrl', ['$location', '$sce', function ($location, $sce) {
    var self = this;
    $scope.setActive = function(current){
        $scope.active = current;
    };

    $scope.amIActive(id)
    {
        if ($scope.active == id)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    };

    }]);
 });
```

Comment: Do you have your tabs set to different states? With a state provider?

Comment: Is, there is! I'm in the bus right now. When I get home, I will proper answer your question. Seems like you're pretty new to Angular, so I will give you some guidelines too.

Comment: @RodrigoSouza, thanks! I am new to Angular and any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: @SimplyZ, I've added an answer. I will verify the piece of code regarding the :ID and update my answer. Meanwhile, you can use this:
.when('/scenario/1' and templateUrl: 'scenario1.html'

Comment: @SimplyZ, the answer is done and finished. :)
About where to start, I would recommend you with a serie of Youtube videos, but it's only available in portuguese. But you can still find lot of good material on Youtube.

If you want to go deeper, I recommend the Angular JS Essentials book and the CodeSchool Angular JS and Javascript courses. Both had helped a lot. And, of course, dig deeper on Google and you will find everything you need to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**USING ROUTE PROVIDER**

With this aproach, you will use the angular module app, inject the [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) so you can manipulate requests. In your index.html file, you can change your div id with a [ng-view](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView), so you can change the code of the ng-view with your ngRoute.

On your Tabset, I've added some links to scenario/:id, so I can use the ID dinamically to find the corresponding html in the $routeProvider.

index.html

```
<html ng-app='app'>
  <body>
    <tabset vertical="false" ng-controller='tabController'>
        <tab a href='#/scenario/1' heading="Scenario 1" ></tab>
        <tab a href='#/scenario/2' heading="Scenario 2"></tab>
        <tab a href='#/scenario/3' heading="Dist as of 12/31/15"></tab>
        <tab a href='#/scenario/4' heading="Custom Label"></tab>
    </tabset>

    <div ng-view>
    </div>

  </body>
    <script src="angular.js">
    <script src="angular-route.js">
    <script src='app.js'>
</html>
```

scenario1.html

```
<div>
  This is scenario 01
</div>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', [ngRoute]);

app.controller('tabController', function(){});

app.config( function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/scenario/:ID',
      {
        controller: 'tabController',
        templateUrl: function($routeParams) {
          return 'scenario' + routeParams.ID + '.html' }
      })
    .otherwise( { template: '<div> Ohh, 404! :D </div> });
});
```

The templateUrl will guide the path to the file while the template will display direct HTML. The templareUrl can receive both a path or a function that return a  path. In this case, I needed acess to the :ID, which is a Route Param, so I needed to inject the $routeParams dependency in order to acess it.

The .otherwise method will guide to the a default 404 page.

**HIDING AND SHOWING CONTENT FROM THE SAME PAGE**

First, everything is on the same page. I'm using [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf), but I could use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) or [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) too. With these three, we can display or hide content based on a scope variable or scope function. In something.html, I'm calling a function on the tabs to set the active tab and, below that, I have all the divs that will only display if the corresponding tab is active.

something.html

```
    <tabset vertical="false" ng-controller='tabController'>
        <tab ng-click='setActive(1)' heading="Scenario 1" ></tab>
        <tab ng-click='setActive(2)' heading="Scenario 2"></tab>
        <tab ng-click='setActive(3)' heading="Dist as of 12/31/15"></tab>
        <tab ng-click='setActive(4)' heading="Custom Label"></tab>
    </tabset>

    <div ng-if='amIActive(1)' id='Scenario1'>
        This is test content 1
    </div>

    <div ng-if='amIActive(2)' id='Scenario2'>
        This is test content 2
    </div>

    <div ng-if='amIActive(3)' id='Scenario3'>
        This is test content 3
    </div>

    <div ng-if='amIActive(4)' id='Scenario4'>
        This is test content 4
    </div>
```

app.js

```
app.controller('tabController', function(){
  $scope.setActive = function(current){
    $scope.active = current;
  };

  $scope.amIActive = function(id) {
    if($scope.active == id){
      return true;
    } else { return false; }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Say I don't want the scenario1 to be coming from another html page.  Instead I want it to be some content on the index.html page.  Do you know how I'd go about doing that?  
    
<div id=scenario1>some content</div>

Can I call scenario1 one the tab gets clicked instead of routing to another html page for scenario1?

Comment: Yes, of course. I will update my answer with two examples of ng-if. Wait a sec.

Comment: I've updated my question to show what my current .js page looks like.

Comment: Got it. And I had updated my answer. I think that would fulfill your needs. Tell me if you need something more. :)

Comment: Hey thanks again for the help.  I've updated my post to incorporate your code, but I think I'm handling my controller incorrectly, can you explain what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @SimplyZ, it was not with your code, was with mine. I've forget to add the annonymous call to the function amIActive(id). I've fixed it now. haha
Ahhh, if this solves your problem, mark this as the best answer. :)

Comment: For some reason the tabs themselves still aren't displaying.  I do get the text from the content though.

Comment: I will still probably mark yours as the answer as it's shown me a few ways to do what I need and has helped me understand Angular quite a bit more.

Comment: Try to add something between '></tab>' só it can be like this '>This is Tab 01</tab>'. Tell me if it worked. My WiFi has gone down, time to call my $internetProvider, haha!

Comment: Aww man, sorry to hear that.  And unfortunately no.  The text just shows up, but not tabs.  "This is a test content 1" through 4 all just show up.

Comment: Wifi is back. Look at that: http://jsfiddle.net/2erkvrsu/
You have to import both bootstrap and ui.bootstrap files. In your angular module, you need to inject ui.bootstrap too.